# how to change display colour of android device in background?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-displaymanager

**I want to add blue light filter in my app but i dont know how can i implement that i am new in android develpment.**

i want to change the colour of screen using seekbar.

i already tried to find a good answer but failed to reach a correct one.

this is my manifest file permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

** i want to achive this feature**

[i want to achive this type of colour change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw2ST.jpg)

Comment: Show some sample like image or something so that it would be easy to understand what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: @Danish  i added the image now can you please help me in that i have no more clue.

Comment: @Nishit Panchal did you got the solution?I am not sure but i think for seekbar you can use circular image view and set its background to desired color that u want and for filter i think you have to filter your layout color.

Comment: @Danish thanks for your reply...i think i need to add more information about the question so here i am giving a brief desc:   so basically i want to create a night mode app which willl run in the background and change the colour of the whole screen to green or any desired colour. i want to create a app similar like this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eyefilter.nightmode.bluelightfilter